# Manual citation of specific references with biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, citing

How can I tell `Biber` that I have just manually cited a specific citation?

This question is *not* about `\mancite`. In `biblatex-chicago` there is a command called `\mancite` which allows you to signal to the ibid-tracker that something has been cited without a `\cite{...}` (or similar) command, so that

```
\cite[30]{smith:ref}.
And see \emph{Reference X}.
See also \cite[31]{smith:ref}.
```

does not produce

> John Smith, *Reference* (Place: Publisher, Year), 30. And see *Reference X*. See also ibid., 31.

but rather

> John Smith, *Reference* (Place: Publisher, Year), 30. And see *Reference X*. See also Smith, *Reference 1*, 31.

What I have *not* been able to figure out is how to signal that a *specific reference* is being cited (for example, for the first time) but that I am manually formatting this particular citation of it. I would like to do this so that

1. subsequent citations of the same reference are in the short format; and
2. the reference appears in the bibliography even if I do not cite it again.

In other words, suppose I define a reference in my `.bib` file which is:

```
@book{CMAG:alchemy,
    Address = {Brussels},
    Editor = {Bidez, Joseph},
    Shorthand = {\emph{CMAG}},
    Title = {Catalogue des manuscrits alchimiques grecs},
    Volumes = {8},
    Year = {1924--1932}}
```

What I would like is to be able to write something like:

```
This is my own way of referring to the CMAG for the first time, p. 10.
\MANUALCITATION{CMAG:alchemy}
[...]
See \cite[11]{CMAG:alchemy}.
```

and have it result in:

> This is my own way of referring to the CMAG for the first time. […] See *CMAG*, vol. 2, p. 11.

instead of:

> This is my own way of referring to the CMAG for the first time. … See Joseph Bidez, ed., *Catalogue des manuscrits alchimiques grecs*, 8 vols. (Brussels, 1924–1932), vol. 2, p. 11 (hereafter cited as CMAG).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make up a "fake" citation command that does nothing (hardly anything) but will still make `biblatex` think it cited the key.

Just define this nice command `\blindcite`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\blindcite}{\unspace}{}{}{}
```

I had to add the `\unspace` macro to get rid of an unwanted space.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{CMAG:alchemy,
    Address = {Brussels},
    Editor = {Bidez, Joseph},
    Shorthand = {\emph{CMAG}},
    Title = {Catalogue des manuscrits alchimiques grecs},
    Volumes = {8},
    Year = {1924--1932}}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\blindcite}{\unspace}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
CMAG \blindcite{CMAG:alchemy} and again \cite[11]{CMAG:alchemy}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is great. For the purposes of ibid tracking (when there is no `Shorthand`), it seemed preferable to include `\mancite` as well, so that I don't end up with a confusing "ibid." coming next. I get the desired result by writing `\blindcite{...}\mancite`, but it doesn't work when I try to fold it into the command declaration, as in `\DeclareCiteCommand{\blindcite}{\unspace\mancite}{}{}{}`. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: @AlexRoberts Try `\DeclareCiteCommand{\blindcite}{\unspace}{}{}{\mancite}`