# Editor-cite: how to create a new command using \DeclareCiteCommand

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

Using `biblatex-chicago`, how can I create a new set of cite commands `\edcite` and `\edvolcite` that on the first citation typeset "`editor-fullname` (`address`: `publisher`, `year`/`date`), `pagerange`/`vol-page-range`" and on subsequent citations typeset "`editor-lastname`, `pagerange`/`vol-page-range`"?

This question is similar to one I have previously asked about [citing editions of medieval texts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390366/citing-editions-of-medieval-texts-with-biblatex-chicago), but I think the answer requires very different solution involving `\DeclareCiteCommand`, not `biblatex-source-division` (which only works in situations where you also want `biblatex` to format the medieval/ancient author's name and book title).

The entry in the bibliography should be normal.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{photios:bibliotheca:henry,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Photios},
    Booktitle = {Bibliothèque},
    Editor = {Henry, René},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Note = {index by Jacques Schamp},
    Publisher = {Les Belles Lettres},
    Title = {Bibliothèque},
    Volumes = {9},
    Year = {1959--1991}}
@book{VettiusValens:Pingree1986,
    Address = {Leipzig},
    Author = {{Vettius Valens}},
    Editor = {Pingree, David},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Publisher = {Teubner},
    Title = {Vettii Valentis Antiocheni Anthologiarum Libri Novem},
    Year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{edcite}

1st time:
\cite[1]{VettiusValens:Pingree1986}.

2nd time:
\cite[2]{VettiusValens:Pingree1986}.

\mancite{}

Again after \verb`\mancite`:
\cite[3]{VettiusValens:Pingree1986}.


\section{edvolcite}

1st time:
\volcite{2}[169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

2nd time:
\volcite{1}[20]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

\mancite{}

Again after \verb`\mancite`:
\volcite{2}[40]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

\end{document}
```

To make this work, I have used `\cite` and `\volcite`. My hope is to replace those with `\edcite` and `\edvolcite` to produce the following output:

> **1 edcite**
>
> 1st time: David Pingree (Leipzig: Teubner, 1986), 1.
>
> 2nd time: ibid., 2.
>
> Again after `\mancite`: Pingree, 3.
>
> **2 edvolcite**
>
> 1st time: René Henry (Paris: Les Belles Lettres,
>   1959–1991), vol. 2, p. 169.
>
> 2nd time: ibid., vol. 1, p. 20.
>
> Again after `\mancite`: Henry, vol. 2, p. 40.

I imagine that the answer will look something like (or use) the command `\blindcite` which @moewe invented in response to a [question I posed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192476/manual-citation-of-specific-references-with-biblatex-chicago/192538#192538) several years ago, but I am wary of messing with `\DeclareCiteCommand` without understanding how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows very simply how to do it. But you will actually probably need more than this if you want other standard citation command equivalents (e.g., `\footcite`, `\autocite`, and `\parencite` plus variants).

It's not so hard though. Look through `biblatex.def` to see how citation commands are declared.

The citation command I've used is also very simply and assumes that all your entries needing `\edcite` are like the ones given in your examples, which may not be true.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{photios:bibliotheca:henry,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Photios},
    Booktitle = {Bibliothèque},
    Editor = {Henry, René},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Note = {index by Jacques Schamp},
    Publisher = {Les Belles Lettres},
    Title = {Bibliothèque},
    Volumes = {9},
    Year = {1959--1991}}
@book{VettiusValens:Pingree1986,
    Address = {Leipzig},
    Author = {{Vettius Valens}},
    Editor = {Pingree, David},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Publisher = {Teubner},
    Title = {Vettii Valentis Antiocheni Anthologiarum Libri Novem},
    Year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{edcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifciteibid}
    and
    not test {\iffirstonpage}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
    {\ifciteseen
       {\printnames[labelname]{editor}}
       {\printnames[given-family]{editor}%
        \newcunit
        \usebibmacro{cpubl+loc+year}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\edcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{edcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\edcites}{\edcite}{\multicitedelim}
\newrobustcmd*{\edvolcite}{\volcitecmd\edcite}
\newrobustcmd*{\edvolcites}{\volcitecmd\edcites}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section{edcite}

1st time:
\edcite[1]{VettiusValens:Pingree1986}.

2nd time:
\edcite[2]{VettiusValens:Pingree1986}.

\mancite{}

Again after \verb`\mancite`:
\edcite[3]{VettiusValens:Pingree1986}.

\section{edvolcite}

1st time:
\edvolcite{2}[169]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

2nd time:
\edvolcite{1}[20]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

\mancite{}

Again after \verb`\mancite`:
\edvolcite{2}[40]{photios:bibliotheca:henry}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you, this works well so far. I haven't tested it with the whole range of complicated `bibtex` entries I'm not even thinking of at the moment, so we'll see what happens. This is also very helpful as a template for how to customize these cite commands.

Comment: I've posted [a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473256/how-to-make-edcite-skip-straight-to-the-short-form-when-biblatex-chicago-short) about extending David Purton's answer to conform with the `short` option of `biblatex-chicago`.