# How to make \edcite skip straight to the short form when biblatex-chicago short option is selected

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

Some time ago, David Purton (@DavidPurton) kindly [devised a set of commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398096/editor-cite-how-to-create-a-new-command-using-declarecitecommand) --- `\edcite{}`, `\edvolcite{}[]{}`, `\transcite{}`, etc. --- for referencing just the editor or translator and publication information of an edition of an ancient or medieval primary text.

My question today involves [the same MWE as before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398096/editor-cite-how-to-create-a-new-command-using-declarecitecommand): is there a simple way to get `\edcite{}` and its siblings to conform to the `short` option in the command `\usepackage[notes, short]{biblatex-chicago}`?

In my original question, I had asked for a command that would print the editor's full name and the book's publication information (`address`: `publisher`, `date`) the first time an edition was referenced and then a short version (just editor's name) on subsequent citations.

What I would like it to do when the `short` option is activated is to use the short version (just editor's name) already the first time the edition is cited.

Comment: Should the first citation be the editor's full name or just family name?

Comment: Just family name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To skip straight to the short form, you can test if *either* the citation has already been seen *or* the toggle `cms@allshort` (which is set by the `short` package option) is set to true.

Change the `edcite` macro to:

```
\newbibmacro*{edcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifciteibid}
    and
    not test {\iffirstonpage}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifciteseen}
      or
      togl {cms@allshort}
     }
       {\printnames[labelname]{editor}}
       {\printnames[given-family]{editor}%
        \newcunit
        \usebibmacro{cpubl+loc+year}}}}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! It's great to have this keyed to the `short` option.