# How to make \edcite use shorteditor if available in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

This question is about the `\edcite` command [created](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398096/editor-cite-how-to-create-a-new-command-using-declarecitecommand) by David Purton (@DavidPurton), who later [updated it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473256/how-to-make-edcite-skip-straight-to-the-short-form-when-biblatex-chicago-short) to be consistent with `biblatex-chicago`'s `short` option.

If possible, I would like to further update the `\edcite` command so that when it is supposed to produce the short form (whether because of a repeated citation or because the `short` option is selected), it first checks whether there is a non-empty `shorteditor` field and if so uses it and if not only then defaults to the `\printnames[given-family]{editor}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes,short]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{basil:hex:mendieta.rudberg1997,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {Basil of Caesarea},
    Editor = {Emmanuel Amand de Mendieta and Rudberg, Stig Y.},
    Publisher = {Akademie Verlag},
    Shortauthor = {Basil},
    Shorteditor = {Mend./Rud.},
    Title = {Homilien zum Hexaemeron},
    Year = {1997}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{edcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifciteibid}
    and
    not test {\iffirstonpage}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifciteseen}
      or
      togl {cms@allshort}
     }
       {\printnames[labelname]{editor}}
       {\printnames[given-family]{editor}%
        \newcunit
        \usebibmacro{cpubl+loc+year}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\edcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{edcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\edcites}{\edcite}{\multicitedelim}
\newrobustcmd*{\edvolcite}{\volcitecmd\edcite}
\newrobustcmd*{\edvolcites}{\volcitecmd\edcites}

\begin{document}
\edcite{basil:hex:mendieta.rudberg1997}
\end{document}
```

Current output:

> Mendieta and Rudberg

Desired output:

> Mend./Rud.

Comment: Oh! I think maybe I misread you question. Do you ever want it to just print the editor family names (like current behaviour with `\printnames[labelname]{editor}`)?

Comment: No, the answer you gave was precisely what I was looking for -- thank you! I tested it without the `short` option, and it does the long version the first time (just as before) and then uses `shorteditor` instead of the family name(s), which is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to adjust the `edcite` macro to test for the presence of the `shorteditor` field.

```
\newbibmacro*{edcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifciteibid}
    and
    not test {\iffirstonpage}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifciteseen}
      or
      togl {cms@allshort}
     }
       {\ifnameundef{shorteditor}
          {\printnames[labelname]{editor}}
          {\printnames[labelname]{shorteditor}}}
       {\printnames[given-family]{editor}%
        \newcunit
        \usebibmacro{cpubl+loc+year}}}}
```